# How to check if a value exist in array and count of value is greater than one?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have an array

```
[
    {"name":"Ticket1","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release1","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release2","delivered":false}]},
    {"name":"Ticket2","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release1","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release2","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"unplanned","delivered":false}]},
    {"name":"Ticket3","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"release1","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"unplanned","delivered":false}]},
    {"name":"Ticket4","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"unplanned","delivered":false}]}
]
```

In the above array, I have to check if releases array contains an "unplanned" entry and count(releases.needToBeDeliver == true) > 0, then unset the "unplanned" entry from releases array.

For example

- In the first index, it will remain as it is because it does not contain any unplanned entry in releases array
- In second index, it contains unplanned entry and needToBeDeliver value is true for more than one time, delete the unplanned entry
- In third index, it contains unplanned entry but the needToBeDeliver is not equal to true, don't delete the unplanned entry
- In forth index, it contains unplanned entry but needToBeDeliver is not true, don't delete the unplanned entry

O/p should be following

```
[
    {"name":"Ticket1","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release1","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release2","delivered":false}]},
    {"name":"Ticket2","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release1","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":true,"name":"release2","delivered":false}]},
    {"name":"Ticket3","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"release1","delivered":false},{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"unplanned","delivered":false}]},
    {"name":"Ticket4","releases":[{"needToBeDeliver":false,"name":"unplanned","delivered":false}]}
]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
tickets.forEach(ticketsData => {
    var i = 0;
    ticketsData.releases.forEach(release => {
        if(release.needToBeDeliver === true){
            i++;
        }       
    });
});
```

But I am not getting how to add second condition in loop to check if unplanned entry exist in releases array of each index. Please help me to proceed with this.

Comment: Try this `if(release.needToBeDeliver === true && releases.name == 'unplanned'){`

Comment: @HassanImam, thing is unplanned entry will never have needToBeDeliver as true, we have to check for other entries in releases array,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement "count(releases.needToBeDeliver == true) > 0" can be rephrased to "there is a release with .needToBeDeliver == true" for which you can use `.some`:

```
data.forEach(d => {
    if (d.releases.some(r => r.needToBeDeliver))
        d.releases = d.releases.filter(r => r.name !== 'unplanned')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for a second condition within any statement can be done very easily by using logical operators.

In your example, simply checking for

```
if(release.needToBeDeliver == true && release.name == "unplanned"){
            i++;
        }
```

will allow you "filtering out" the elements that need to be delivered and have the name "unplanned". Hope, this is what you were looking for.

Comment: but the unplanned entry will never have flag needToBeDeliver as true. The above condition will check both needToBeDeliver and name for each release. Where we have to check releases array should have unplanned entry and count of needToBeDeliver flag as true is greater than one when counted for all indexes of releases array

Answer (score 1):

You cou get the count first and then filter the `releases`.

```js
var array = [{ name: "Ticket1", releases: [{ needToBeDeliver: true, name: "release1", delivered: false }, { needToBeDeliver: true, name: "release2", delivered: false }] }, { name: "Ticket2", releases: [{ needToBeDeliver: true, name: "release1", delivered: false }, { needToBeDeliver: true, name: "release2", delivered: false }, { needToBeDeliver: false, name: "unplanned", delivered: false }] }, { name: "Ticket3", releases: [{ needToBeDeliver: false, name: "release1", delivered: false }, { needToBeDeliver: false, name: "unplanned", delivered: false }] }, { name: "Ticket4", releases: [{ needToBeDeliver: false, name: "unplanned", delivered: false }] }];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    var count = o.releases.reduce((s, { needToBeDeliver }) => s + needToBeDeliver, 0);
    o.releases = o.releases.filter(a => !(a.name === 'unplanned' && count));
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following:

```
var result = tickets.map(ticket => {
  if (!ticket.releases.some(r => r.needToBeDeliver)) return ticket;
  return Object.assign(ticket, { releases: ticket.releases.filter(r => r.name !== 'unplanned') });
});
```

You check if there is a release that contains a `needToBeDeliver` return the original if that's false. When true, filter out any `unplanned` releases.